# How to create a ranged frequency table using Excel Cube functions

Tags: excel, mdx, powerpivot

What I want is to create something like this (see image) in Excel that pulls in the frequency of my chosen category from a table within my PowerPivot data model. The output would also need to be dynamically filtered via a cell reference.

[image]

Using the below data set as an example:

```
Week 1  A
Week 1  A
Week 1  A
Week 1  A
Week 1  A
Week 1  B
Week 1  B
Week 1  C
Week 1  D
Week 2  A
Week 2  A
Week 2  A
Week 2  A
Week 2  A
Week 2  A
```

If I filtered to Week 1 through my set expression, the following output would be produced

```
1   2
2-4 1
5+  1
```

However, if filtered to Week 2, this output would be produced

```
1   0
2-4 0
5+  1
```

I say 'set expression' because I am assuming the way to do this is through the CUBESET function possibly with a MDX FILTER function and the CUBESETCOUNT functions though I am open to other suggestions. Even though the example doesn't show it, I need the expression to filter **multiple dimensions** from my cube, in particular, date, which is found in my calendar table.

I also understand that I could create specific measures within PowerPivot to handle this (sample formula below), but I would like to know if this is possible via the CUBESET function.

```
Freq (5+):=CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT([myColumn]),
        FILTER(myTable, 
            COUNTROWS(FILTER('myTable', [myColumn] = EARLIER([myColumn]))) >=5      )
    )
```

I am also open to creating a helper column within my Powerpivot table.

Thanks,